# File or directory not found even though it exists

Tags: python, file

this is my code to open a file and get the text from it :

```
    f = open("C:/Users/muthaharsh/Documents/Harsh/News 
    Project/Part3/Testing_purposes/Downloads3/Are-you-being-churned-,- 
    Mint.txt","r+")
    text = f.readlines()
    print(text)
```

but i keep getting the error :

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/muthaharsh/Documents/Harsh/News Project/Part3/Testing_purposes/Downloads3/Are-you-being-churned-,-Mint.txt'

What code do i write to be able to do this ? 
Thanks in advance ...

Comment: try using `r'path/to/file'`. Are you running code on Windows?.

Comment: i tried running this as you suggested : 
        f = open(r"C:/Users/muthaharsh/Documents/Harsh/News Project/Part3/Testing_purposes/Downloads3/Are-you-being-churned-,-Mint.txt","r+")

but still got the same error

And yes i am running code on Windows 10.

Comment: Ok. To make things easy: Create a sample text file on your desktop and use `r'/path/to/file.txt'`. If code works then good, otherwise there must be some naming problem.

Comment: Try  os.path.exists(filepath)

Answer (score 0):

It's the whitespace in the path to file. Either use

```
r"C:/Users/muthaharsh/Documents/Harsh/News Project/Part3/Testing_purposes/Downloads3/Are-you-being-churned-,-Mint.txt"
```

or remove the whitespace in the filepath.

Comment: Maybe it's something to do with the weird -,- bit in the file name? If that doesn't work, I'd double check that it is the correct file path.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the code on windows add r before your filepath string.
Another way is that you can provide your input file as system arguments.

`import sys
 file_name = sys.argv[1]
 with open(file_name, 'r') as f1:
   file_text = f1.read()
 print(file_text)`

eg: [python program for reading the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxHYW.png)

you can run the code considering script is saved as readFile.py: 
D:\Programs>python readFile.py D:\test.txt
output: This is a sample file
        Here is the text